# How to merge two multidimensional arrays without overwriting existing keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add two multidimensional arrays. The function should be the exact same as adding the arrays together like so: $new_array = $array1 + $array2, except it should work with multidimensional arrays. This means that $array2 should not overwrite existing key values.

Example: let's say I have the following $default_array:

```
array
  'something' => int 0
  'nested' => 
    array (size=3)
      'a' => null
      'b' => null
      'c' => null
```

And the following $user_array:

```
array
  'something' => int 1000
  'nested' => 
    array (size=3)
      'a' => 1
  'new' => int 4
```

Adding the two together (like $user_array + $default_array) should give me:

```
array (size=4)
      'something' => int 1000
      'nested' => 
        array (size=3)
          'a' => 1
          'b' => null
          'c' => null
      'new' => int 4
```

Currently, it seems that if I add the two multidimensional arrays, the overwriting feature seems to only apply to the first array dimension. This means that in this case, 'nested' already exists in the $user_array, so it wouldn't append the other values.

EDIT: I should also mention that this would need to work with unlimited amount of dimensions.

EDIT 2: I just tried to apply Rain's answer, and it's not working as intended. First off, I'm getting "undefined index" notices. Secondly, the output it not as I wanted. Consider the following arrays:

```
        $default = array(
            'a' => array(
                'a' => 'a',
                'b' => 'b',
                'c' => 'c',
                ),
            );

        $user = array(
            'b' => 1,
            'a' => array(
                'b' => 'something',
                'c' => 'something else',
                'd' => 'd',
                ),
            'c' => 2);
```

The output I'm getting with Rain's function is this:

```
array (size=3)
  'a' => 
    array (size=3)
      'a' => string 'a' (length=1)
      'b' => string 'b' (length=1)
      'c' => string 'c' (length=1)
  'b' => int 1
  'c' => int 2
```

In this example, the 'b' and 'c' keys in the sub-array should be 'something' and 'something else', respectively. I'm not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: what code do you have for now?

Comment: I don't have anything ATM. I thought that doing something like was common and had an easy implementation, but I guess I'll have to do build a recursive function for this.

Comment: this is very complicated process cause you can have thousands of internal arrays which you will have to compare for values.. you will have to come up with an algorithm to accomplish this.. I will see if I can come up with something..

Comment: I see, thanks. Though you wouldn't have to compare values, only to check if a key already exists. If it exists => do not overwrite. If it does not exist => add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function is definitely the way to go here. I just whipped up the following. Note the use of `&` in the function declaration of `fill_in_aux`. This causes the second argument (called `$default`) to be passed by reference, instead of by value. It is wrapped in `fill_in` so that the real "default" array is not modified.

```
function fill_in($user, $default) {
    fill_in_aux($user, $default);
    return $default;
}

function fill_in_aux($user, &$default) {
    foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            fill_in_aux($user[$key], $default[$key]);
        } else {
            $default[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that anything that is set in the `$default` array should be overwritten by anything that exists in the `$user` array, even if a key in the `$user` array is set to `null`. To change this behavior, add another `if` statement in the `else` clause in `fill_in_aux`.

---

### Example Usage

With your example arrays, the output of

```
print_r(fill_in($user_array, $default_array));
```

is

```
Array
(
    [something] => 1000
    [nested] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] =>
            [c] =>
        )

    [new] => 4
)
```

---

### Breakdown

Normally, when calling a function in PHP, parameters are passed by *value*: the function gets a ***copy*** of the passed in variable. This means that the function can do whatever it wants to the parameters but when the function returns, the original variable that was passed is unaffected.

When an parameter is prefaced by an `&` symbol, the parameter is passed by ***reference***, instead of being copied. When the function makes modifications to the parameter, it is actually making changes directly to the variable that was passed in.

For more information, check out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Wow, this works pretty well. I'm having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around how this works with the reference. How could `$default[$key] = $value;` simply work like that if you're deep within the array? Why wouldn't it be something like `$default[$key][$anotherkey][$yetanotherkey] = $value;`? Would be awesome to get a breakdown on how this works.

Comment: @user371699 I added a small breakdown. For more information, I recommend checking out the PHPDOCs link I added as well as looking up some information on various types of parameter passing.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I appreciate your time in helping me out with this; I learned a lot!

Comment: It seems something is not working right. Can you please check out my edit in the OP?

Comment: @user371699 I get the correct output without errors with your new arrays. Are you sure you are calling `fill_in` with the `$user` array as the first parameter and `$default` as the second? That is critical. Edit: Here is my test: http://pastebin.com/LmwfZegT

Comment: You're absolutely right. Something was messed up in my code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using **`array_merge_recursive()`** (not just array_merge())
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

```
<?php
$defaultarray = array(
'something' => 0,
  'nested' => 
    array (
      'a' => null,
      'b' => null,
      'c' => null));

$newArray = array(
  'something' => 1000, 
  'nested' => 
    array ('a' => 1,
  'new' => 4));

$mergedArray = array_merge_recursive($defaultarray, $newArray);
echo print_r($mergedArray,true);
?>
```

**Output:**
Array ( [something] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1000 ) [nested] => Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 ) [b] => [c] => [new] => 4 ) )

Comment: No sir, this does not work properly for multidimensional arrays. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Note your output: `"something" => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1000 )`; this is not what OP is asking for. Some things just can't be done with the standard PHP library.

Comment: user371699 was asking for a way to merge together two arrays without removing/overwriting elemens. When the arrays $defaultarray['something'] = 0 and $newArray['something'] = 1000 is merged, then an array is created of these two values $mergedArray['something'] = array(0, 1000). I can't see any problem with that? I'm aware that PHP core functions can't solve every problem! :-)

Comment: @Rain - of course it depends on HOW the merging process should work when merging two values when the arrays have the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I am amazes that no one offered you the native function `array_replace_recursive()` seven years ago.  @bestprogrammerintheworld was on the right track but chose the wrong recursive call.

Using ANYTHING other than this function is going to be unnecessary code bloat and very likely to be worse performance.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/71R1i))

```
var_export(
    array_replace_recursive($default, $user)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 
  array (
    'a' => 'a',
    'b' => 'something',
    'c' => 'something else',
    'd' => 'd',
  ),
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => 2,
)
```

Comment: @timetofly the English explanation of what you need is different from your expected result.  If this answer is correct, I'll edit your question to fix up the conflict in your requirements.